# why does "Number" make the "else if" work here?

Tags: javascript, multiple-conditions

I have a task to play a little with if/else if.
i don't understand why, when I write my code like the example below, the "else if(age === 18)" part doesn't work. it shows up as "undefined". the other 2 work.
But, when i add (Number(age) at all of them, it works. Why is that? why can i use 2/3 without "Number", but i need it to use 3/3?

```
var age = prompt("Please type your age!");
if (age < 18) {
    alert("Sorry, you are too young to drive this car. Powering off");
} else if (age === 18) {
    alert("Congratulations on your first year of driving. Enjoy the ride!");
} else if (age > 18) {
    alert("Powering On. Enjoy the ride!");
}
```

Comment: what shows up as undefined?

Comment: You variable `age` is a string, you try to compare it to an integer value. `===` is strict and when comparing a string to an integer will return `false`. Either use `==` to losely compare the values or better, parse your `age` variable to an integer value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `prompt` returns a string.

The operators `<` and `>` will allow you to compare a string to a number, by pre-converting the string to a number and then comparing them. Read [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839/) for more info on this, called "Type Coersion" in JS.

The `===` operator however will not do this type coercion/conversion, it will directly compare `"18"` with `18` and return false.

To fix this, you can instead use the other equals operator, `==`, which does include type coercion.

However, a better way of doing it would be to check the input is definitely a number, like this:

```js
var age = Number(prompt("Please type your age!"));

if (Number.isNaN(age)) {
    alert("Try again with a number");
} else if (age < 18) {
    alert("Sorry, you are too young to drive this car. Powering off");
} else if (age === 18) {
    alert("Congratulations on your first year of driving. Enjoy the ride!");
} else if (age > 18) {
    alert("Powering On. Enjoy the ride!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers guys :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the string to a number. The easiest way is to take an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus).

With a number, you can check with a strict comparison [Identity/strict equality operator `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity) against a number, because you have at least the same type.

```js
var age = +prompt("Please type your age!");
if (age < 18) {
    alert("Sorry, you are too young to drive this car. Powering off");
} else if (age === 18) {
    alert("Congratulations on your first year of driving. Enjoy the ride!");
} else {
    alert("Powering On. Enjoy the ride!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`prompt` returns a string, which cannot be strictly equal to the number `18` since the types are different. It would work, however, if you used loose equality (`==`).

The simplest way to convert it to a number would be to use the unary plus operator, which has much the same function as the `Number` function.

```
var age = +prompt("Please type your age!");
```

Answer (score 0):

cause `prompt` returns a stirng.
But `<` & `>` operators converts string to a number

```js
var age = prompt("Please type your age!");
if (age < 18) {
    alert("Sorry, you are too young to drive this car. Powering off");
} else if (age === '18') {
    alert("Congratulations on your first year of driving. Enjoy the ride!");
} else if (age > 18) {
    alert("Powering On. Enjoy the ride!");
}
```

Comment: `>` and `<` do not implicitly convert a string to a number. You can often have problems when `"100"` shows as being less than `"20"`, for example.